# RealmSwift v0.96 - Use of undeclared type "Results"

Tags: swift, realm

I updated my RealmSwift to version 0.96 and now get an error when I want to write an extension for Result:

```
Use of undeclared type "Results"
```

that's what I want did before. There were some changes about Result and List in the latest updates but I don't know how to change my code:

```
extension Results {
    func toArray<T>(ofType: T.Type) -> [T] {
        var array = [T]()
        for var i = 0; i < count; i++ {
            if let result = self[i] as? T {
                array.append(result)
            }
        }

        return array
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you import the library in the file in which this extension lives?

Comment: Yes, I can even jump to the declaration.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi: You were looking at Realm Objective, while Mika is trying to extend Realm Swift.

Comment: Ak! You're right - stupid of me. The header is for bridging to ObjC, so it was the Obj-C header.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using CocoaPods with `use_frameworks!`, or do you use your bridging header file (or some other way to include RealmSwift).

If you are using CocoaPods with `use_frameworks!`, make sure you include the reference to RealmSwift in your file defining the extension.

`import RealmSwift`

**EDIT:** Yup, this works for me:

```
import RealmSwift

extension Results {
    func wow() -> String {
        return "test"
    }
}
```

Also, converting your Results to an array can be done much easier, more like this:

```
var someObjects = realm.objects(SomeObjectType).map { $0 }
```

This returns an `[SomeObjectType]` type of array.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work. 
I went back to the old XCode version because Realm had some trouble with Swift 2.1

Comment: This is probably fixed with version 0.96.2.